# Android server PC client communication

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am working on a problem where i have to send data from PC application (written in java) to android application (java).
It is a cash register application that need to display bill details on android app. While there is no bill, android app need to display something else (pictures etc.) Cash register application already exists, it is desktop PC software.

What is the best way to do this?
It is currently done with writing and reading from a file, but i would like to do it in a better way.
I start to work with sockets, where android app is a servers waiting for cash register application on PC to start connection. When this happen, connection is open and cash register is sending JSON Strings until the end of a bill.

I chose android to be server because of the possibility that one cash register have more than one android connected so it can display bill details on more than one "screen", and also to make possible that android app keep specific port always open and listen on it for client.

Is this a good way to do it? I just read about possibility that socket connection may die during the non-use period and that could be hardware issue. I read also about RMI java and don't know if i should go that way. I have never worked on communication between devices so i appreciate every suggestion.

Comment: Set up a [REST API](https://restfulapi.net)

Comment: `where android app is a servers waiting for cash register to start connection. ` I thought you said the Android app would communicate with a java application on pc.

Comment: Yes, cash register application on PC, sorry, i will edit post

Comment: Further i would make Android a client. It gets data from your cash register application which you would make a server. That java server can have many clients.

Comment: @blackapps Doesn't client initiated communication? Android app would be only a display, with no user interaction with device. Plus, i would like to make configuration on PC side, so i don't need to configure every android device with IP address of the cash register application, just to do it on PC side. This way, if user want to add new android device, i could remotely configure if through screen share on PC as part of support

Comment: @TA i will look into REST API for this, thank you

Comment: If the Android devices ran servers your pc application should remember all -changing- ip addresses of them. Its much easier to give your pc a fixed ip. Every client would then use that ip to connect.

Comment: On the moment a client connects to the pc application you can configure it.(what ever that would be). Further i have no idea what you mean with screen share.

Comment: for screen share, i ment on teamviewer, anydesk, etc

Answer (score 1):

I did as suggested and changed logic. I made PC server, and android client.

This is the code for test server app if anyone needs it. It is simple server that send messages entered in terminal to client over chosen port.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    while (true) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            while (true) {
                if (socket.isConnected()) {
                    System.out.println("connected");
                }
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                // Reading data using readLine
                String name = bufferedReader.readLine();
                System.out.println(name);

                dataOutputStream.writeUTF(name);
                if (false) break;
            }

            socket.close();
            serverSocket.close();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```